# Изменить выдачу в классе Stack

Tags: c++, классы, стек

Не получается изменить формат распечатки вектора в классе. Нужно, чтобы содержимое выходило лесенкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А выходят просто все эти же числа в столб. Пробовал также через вложенные циклы, но либо ошибка выходит, либо  то же самое. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить. Спасибо!
Код:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename It>
void PrintRange(It range_begin, It range_end) {
    for (auto it = range_begin; it != range_end; ++it) {
        cout << *it << " "s;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename Type>
class Stack {
public:
    void Push(const Type& element) {
        elements_.push_back(element);
    }
    void Pop() {
        elements_.pop_back();
    }
    const Type& Peek() const {
        return elements_[elements_.size() - 1];
       
    }
    Type& Peek() {
        return elements_[elements_.size() - 1]; 
    }
    void Print() const {
        if (IsEmpty()) {
            return;
       }
        for (auto x : elements_) {
            
            cout << x << " ";
            cout << endl;
      }
    }
    uint64_t Size() const {
        return elements_.size();
    }
    bool IsEmpty() const {
        return elements_.empty();
    }

private:
    vector<Type> elements_;
};

int main() {
    Stack<int> stack;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        stack.Push(i);
        stack.Print();
    }
    while (!stack.IsEmpty()) {
        stack.Pop();
        stack.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: "А выходят просто все эти же числа в столб." - ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for (auto x : elements_) {
      cout << x << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
```